# Error with computer Function in Vuejs / Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to calculate Total Tax Amount after an input using Vuejs in a Laravel App. My computer Function to calculate total is not working. where did i miss ?

This is my vuejscode:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
rinvoices: {    
        amount:'',
        tva:'',        
},
},
 methods: {
        addRinvoice: function () {
        axios.post('/addrinvoice', this.rinvoices)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.rinvoices = {
                         id: 0,
                          amount: response.data.etat.amount,
                           tva: response.data.etat.tva,     
                    };
                }

            })
    },
    },
computed: {
total: function () {
    var amount= this.rinvoices.amount;
    var tax= this.rinvoices.tva;
    var taxamount= amount*tax;
    var t=taxamount + amount;
    return t;
}
},
});
```

Error is my funnction is not calculating **taxamount + amount**, but place the value like that **taxamount** and **Amount**.
example : instead of 10+5=15 it's 10 5

Comment: `response` is undefined inside total() method.

Comment: yes sir thank you, i fixed that, please check out my eddited post, the function is not calculating total

Comment: `amount` and `tva` seem to be strings, not a numbers. Use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `taxamount` & `amount` from String to Number first then do addition.

Change to: `var t = +taxamount + +amount;`

```js
total: function () {
   var amount= this.rinvoices.amount;
   var tax= this.rinvoices.tva;
   var taxamount= amount*tax;
   var t = +taxamount + +amount;
   return t;
}
```